# How to fix the problem of date_default_timezone_set()?

Tags: php

I have a problem in my php command which i can't figure out where the error is, i use the php function `date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Algiers')` but the problem is that that function returns a wrong time only, the date is correct but the time isn't. i've tried this with different time zones. please any help.

```
 date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Algiers');
 print_r(date('m/d/y g:i A'));
```

Comment: Dont seem to be able to reproduce this error. See https://3v4l.org/8OBmg

Comment: Have you tried to verify the return value from `date_default_timezone_set`? It may return false...

Comment: Try var_dump(date_default_timezone_get()); by date_default_timezone_set.